# Getting only some tags <p> using BeautifulSoup from website

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I try to getting text from only selectet tags, for example:

```
<div class="article-container">
  <p>tekst 1</p> <!-- this tag -->
  <p>none</p>
  <p>tekst 2</p> <!-- this tag -->
  <p>none</p>
  <p>tekst 3</p> <!-- this tag -->
  <p>none</p>
  <p>tekst 4</p> <!-- this tag -->
</div>
```

I try get 'tekst 1 tekst 2 tekst 3 tekst 4' (but the text in the tags is completely different 'tekst 1' etc. are just examples),

My simple python function looks like this:

```
def get_article(url):
    page = requests.get(str(url))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

    article = soup.find(class_='article-container')

    article_only = article.text

    return(article_only)
```

But he returns the whole text. Is there a way to get selected elements as in the above example using BS?

Comment: how do you want to select tags? Do you want just the text inside `p` tags? what is `none`?

Comment: First, `article-container` class, doesn't exist in your html. Then, it's not very clear if you look for tags which include the word `tekst` or if you want the tags which are not empty or eventually one tag out of two (the odd one)

Comment: I want to get only text but from tags 1, 3, 5, 7 of those in which I added a comment next to it.

Comment: I am sorry, I corrected my error in the question above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as you want only the 1,3,5,7 element, you can do this:

**CODE:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

html = """<div class="article-intro">
<p>tekst 1</p>
<p>none</p>
<p>tekst 2</p>
<p>none</p>
<p>tekst 3</p>
<p>none</p>
<p>tekst 4</p>
</div>"""

page = soup(html, 'html.parser')
div = page.find('div',{'class':'article-intro'})
ps = div.find_all('p')
for i in range(len(ps)):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        print(ps[i].text)
```

**output:**

```
tekst 1
tekst 2
tekst 3
tekst 4
```

Comment: the question so far is not very clear, your answer might be the good one if he's looking for odd tags

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expression `re` and search for text.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html='''<div class="article-intro">
<p>tekst 1</p>
<p>none</p>
<p>tekst 2</p>
<p>none</p>
<p>tekst 3</p>
<p>none</p>
<p>tekst 4</p>
</div>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
for item in soup.find('div', class_='article-intro').find_all('p', text=re.compile('tekst')):
    print(item.text)
```

### Output:

```
tekst 1
tekst 2
tekst 3
tekst 4
```

---

Or you can use python `lambda` function.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''<div class="article-intro">
<p>tekst 1</p>
<p>none</p>
<p>tekst 2</p>
<p>none</p>
<p>tekst 3</p>
<p>none</p>
<p>tekst 4</p>
</div>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
for item in soup.find('div', class_='article-intro').find_all(lambda tag:tag.name=='p' and 'tekst' in tag.text):
    print(item.text)
```

### Output:

```
tekst 1
tekst 2
tekst 3
tekst 4
```

Answer (score 0):

[find_all()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) function always return a list.

NOTE: The `text` argument is an old name, since BeautifulSoup 4.4.0 it's called `string`.

> Although string is for finding strings, you can combine it with
>   arguments that find tags: Beautiful Soup will find all tags whose
>   .string matches your value for string. This code finds the tags whose
>   .string is “tekst”:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import re  

html = '''<div class="article-container">
<p>tekst 1</p>
<p>none</p>
<p>tekst 2</p>
<p>none</p>
<p>tekst 3</p>
<p>te</p>
<p>tekst 4</p>
</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
article = soup.select("div[class='article-container']")[0]
article_only = article.find_all(string=re.compile("tekst"))
print(article_only)
```

**O/P:**

```
['tekst 1', 'tekst 2', 'tekst 3', 'tekst 4']
```

Answer (score 0):

Some different options depending on what you actually want to do going forwards. Using bs4 4.7.1.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<div class="article-container">
  <p>tekst 1</p> <!-- this tag -->
  <p>none</p>
  <p>tekst 2</p> <!-- this tag -->
  <p>none</p>
  <p>tekst 3</p> <!-- this tag -->
  <p>none</p>
  <p>tekst 4</p> <!-- this tag -->
</div>
'''

soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
#odd indices
items = [item.text for item in soup.select('.article-container p:nth-child(odd)')]
print(items)

#excluding None
items = [item.text for item in soup.select('.article-container p:not(:contains("none"))')]
print(items)

#including tekst
items = [item.text for item in soup.select('.article-container p:contains("tekst")')]
print(items)

#providing nth list
items = [item.text for item in soup.select('.article-container p:nth-of-type(1), .article-container p:nth-of-type(3), .article-container p:nth-of-type(5), .article-container p:nth-of-type(7)')]
print(items)
```